# Ao enviar dados via POST não insere na base de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, wordpress

Tenho este formulário e script numa página:

```
<section class="hide-section" id="produto_1"> 
<form class="form-validate" id="feedback_form">
    <div class="campo">
        <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
        </div>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Nome do Produto">Nome do Produto</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoProd" name="DescricaoProd" required="" style="width:350px">
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoUnid" name="DescricaoUnid" style="width:160px" required="" size="120">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn_contact" type="button">Registo</button>
</form>
</section> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(".btn_contact").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./inserir",
                    data: $("#feedback_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        if ($.trim(data) == 'true') {
                            $("#feedback_form").find('input').val(''); //clear text
                            $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message
                        } else {
                            $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
</script>
```

Na página inserir tenho este código php:

```
$name = isset($_POST["DescricaoProd"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoProd"] : '';
$unid = isset($_POST["DescricaoUnid"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoUnid"] : '';
if (!empty($name) && !empty($unid)) {  
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}    

$sql = "INSERT INTO ProdHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";
if ($conn->query($sql)) { // check for === TRUE is not necessary
   // either put the second query in here, or just enjoy the success
} else {
   // get the error, throw a message...
}
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO StockHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";
if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
} else {
    // get the error, throw a message...
}
$conn->close();
```

Estava a inserir na tabela da base de dados e deixou de inserir, mas também não dá nenhum erro na consola. Alguém pode ajudar a identificar o problema?

Comment: Para encontrar esse problema eu daria um `echo $sql1` logo abaixo da variável e em seguida colocaria essa query diretamente na base de dados para verificar o real problema.

Comment: @David Alves, Tentei fazer o que disse mas não recebo resultado nenhum, testei as queries no mysql e estão a funcionar

Comment: Você já se certificou que os dados do post estão chegando certos pro php?

Comment: Ppde postar aqui o valor das variáveis `$sql` e `$sql1`?

Comment: Como posso verificar se os valores do post chegam ao php?

Comment: eu na página do php já fiz `var_dump ($sql);` e `var_dump ($sql1);` e também echo, mas não mostra os resultados das variáveis. Também fiz `print_r ($name);` `print_r ($unid);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fiz algumas alterações no seu código

**Script - acrescentei `dataType: "json",`**

```
$(".btn_contact").click(function () {

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./inserir",
  data: $("#feedback_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
  dataType: "json",
      success: function (data)
      {
         if ($.trim(data) == 'true') {
           $("#feedback_form").find('input').val(''); //clear text
           $("#success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message
         } else {
           $("#error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
         }
      }
  });

});
```

**No HTML - para mostrar mensagem**

```
<div id="success_messages" class="hide">sucessso</div>
<div id="error_message" class="hide">erro</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
     display: none;
}
```

**Pagina inserir**

```
$name = isset($_POST["DescricaoProd"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoProd"] : '';
$unid = isset($_POST["DescricaoUnid"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoUnid"] : '';

if (!empty($name) && !empty($unid)) {  
   echo json_encode("true");
} else {
    echo json_encode("false");
}

$conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "nome_DB");

$sql = "INSERT INTO ProdHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";
if ($conn->query($sql)) { // check for === TRUE is not necessary
   // either put the second query in here, or just enjoy the success
} else {
   // get the error, throw a message...
}

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO StockHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM StockHigieneteste");

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) {
    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
} else {
    // get the error, throw a message...
}


$conn->close();
```

**OBS:** Na pagina inserir você esqueceu de fazer um SELECT para poder retornar o total do numero de linhas

> **Se com as correções acima continua a  dar problemas, e já que é um servidor local, o seu problema pode estar no mysql workbench. Reinicie o mysql workbench.**

Comment: Agradeço a sua ajuda, mas não insere na tabela, mas não dá nenhum erro na consola.

Comment: sim insere como disse mas aqui na minha aplicação web não está a inserir, mas se forçar um erro na página onde tenho o php ele deterá logo o erro, mas não estou a conseguir entender porque não está a inserir.

Comment: Qual é a estrutura da tabela?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ProdHigieneteste (
  IDProd int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  DescricaoProd varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  DescricaoUnid varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  Ativo varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (IDProd)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=309 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;`

Comment: mas a variável ativo não existe no formulário, também tenho de criar esse input no formulário?

Comment: É verdade, não precisa, agora que reparei que é `DEFAULT '1'`

Comment: Criei a tabela com o seu CREATE TABLE e continua inserindo direitino aqui

Comment: será que estou a ter este problema por estar a usar o wordpress?

Comment: Estranho isso,de  wordpress não entendo, mas não tem nada a ver com PHP. Alguma coisa deve estar passando desapercebido, e pior que não acusa erro.

Comment: Já testou colocar senha errada na conexão pra ver se acusa erro?

Comment: Eu por exemplo se tirar uma { ou um ) na consola do chrome acusa o error intern 500.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77971/discussion-between-iniciante-and-leo-caracciolo).

Comment: Não sei mais o que dizer, o código está certo, a tabela também está correta, aqui no meu servidor funciona corretamente.